# Radius around route google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have searched for the solution of my problem but could not find it.
I want to make the radius around the Google map route.

For example if i am drawing route from the location AMSTERDAM to BERLIN and i want to draw the some shade around the route base line.
Please see the image, I want to do exact given in image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zYgr.png
I am unable to do this, if any one have the idea to do such thing, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a second `directionsRenderer` object with a bigger `strokeWeight`. http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/N5v3f/

Answer (score 0):

you cannot draw circle around the route but if you can draw a circle and create a route inside the circle then it will be possible

Javascript to Draw circle

```
var map; // map object

var radius; // Radius of circle in miles.

var center; // LatLng of center point of circle

var draw_circle = null;  // object of google maps polygon for redrawing the circle
 function DrawCircle(rad) {

    rad *= 1600; // convert to meters if in miles
    if (draw_circle != null) {
        draw_circle.setMap(null);
    }
    draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: center,
        radius: rad,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
    });
}
```

You can change the radius property of google map to change the circle width and you will find the route inside that circle after that.